# What is an "optimal ensemble" used to demonstrate quantum steering?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, quantum-entanglement, representation-theory, non-locality

I am reading [Wiseman et al. (2007)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.140402?casa_token=ZEsGhZeeTRkAAAAA%3ApWinSIEi9Yj-i5vR5LuMZQmUrfD7767sNX6rCxQr9yvtnOhcx1ggnDdyecn_SqEuDSvNgGBK4zheq2Y) and [Jones et al. (2007)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/15037379.pdf) papers on quantum steering. They relied on the existence of "optimal ensembles" for a Local Hidden State theory. They make use of group theory to find them from what I understood. I am confused as to how does group theory come in, in the first place. How do they find these "optimal ensembles". I am very confused.

Comment: It would be helpful if you give complete information here so that people don't need to go and try to find the papers for which you did not provide complete references or links.

Comment: Thank you. I will add the references/ links.